# How to set dynamic path for background-image in Pug(Jade)

Tags: pug

I have some object in Pug and want to render list with help this:

```
var categoryList = [
  {
    img: "/src/img/images/category1.jpg",
    name: "Category 1"
  },
  {
    img: "/src/img/images/category2.jpg",
    name: "Category 2"
  },
  {
    img: "/src/img/images/category3.jpg",
    name: "Category 3"
  }
];
```

I want to set background-image for every element, but can't find right syntax.
How i can do this?

```
each category in categoryList
  a.category-item(href='catalog.html')
    // My try doesn't work
    // .category-item_img(style='background-image : url(category[x].img);')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be either of the following:

```
// with string concatenation
each category in categoryList
  a.category-item(href='catalog.html')
    .category-item_img(style='background-image: url(' + category.img + ')')

// with template literals
each category in categoryList
  a.category-item(href='catalog.html')
    .category-item_img(style=`background-image: url(${category.img})`)
```

See the [Attribute Interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation) section of the [Pug Documentation](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) for more information.